# How to get 2 or 3 radial location's middle point (Latitude, Longtitude)

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I tried to use [haversine](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) i couldn't succeed
Basically my problem is i have 3 map locations with their Lat and Long values.
What i trying to do is getting this triangle's middle point.

Here is the picture

[image]

I Have the locations of H, F and I points. i need to know question mark's location.
41.040035,28.984026
41.040868,28.985807
41.039136,28.984981

PHP, MYSQL or Objective C any of these languages are ok as an answer.
Even suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked this example : http://geomidpoint.com/example.html

And wrote a function in PHP, hope this is helpful ...

[edit] i forgot to convert to radians for the calculations so it gave a different output, so now it should be working fine ...

```
   <?php

function middlepoint($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2,$lat3,$lon3){
    $w1=1095.75;$w2=730.5;$w3=365.25;$tw=$w1+$w2+$w3;   //weighting factors

    $x1=cos(floatval(deg2rad($lat1)))*cos(floatval(deg2rad($lon1)));$y1=cos(floatval(deg2rad($lat1)))*sin(floatval(deg2rad($lon1)));$z1=sin(floatval(deg2rad($lat1)));$x2=cos(floatval(deg2rad($lat2)))*cos(floatval(deg2rad($lon2)));$y2=cos(floatval(deg2rad($lat2)))*sin(floatval(deg2rad($lon2)));$z2=sin(floatval(deg2rad($lat2)));$x3=cos(floatval(deg2rad($lat3)))*cos(floatval(deg2rad($lon3)));$y3=cos(floatval(deg2rad($lat3)))*sin(floatval(deg2rad($lon3)));$z3=sin(floatval(deg2rad($lat3)));  //convert lat/long to cartesian (x,y,z) coordinates

    $x = ($x1*$w1+$x2*$w2+$x3*$w3)/$tw;$y=($y1*$w1+$y2*$w2+$y3*$w3)/$tw;$z=($z1*$w1+$z2*$w2+$z3*$w3)/$tw;   //Compute combined weighted cartesian coordinates

    $lon=atan2($y,$x);$hyp=sqrt(pow($x,2)+pow($y,2));$lat=atan2($z,$hyp);   //Convert cartesian coordinate to latitude and longitude for the midpoint

    $midpoint[0] = $lon * (180/pi());$midpoint[1] = $lat * (180/pi());  //Convert from radians to degrees

    return $midpoint;   //return an array(lat,lon);

}

$test = middlepoint(41.040035,28.984026,41.040868,28.985807,41.039136,28.984981);
print_r($test);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the scale that you are working at you won't come to any harm treating the lat/long coordinates as plane coordinates and using the elementary operations of Euclidean geometry for figuring out positions such as the middle point of a triangle.

You might also be interested in [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: but i am afraid of a couple of work could be tiring for the system, thank you though. i'll try anway